# std::tr2::sys is not available in latest version of C++

Tags: c++11, visual-studio-2019

I'm using complete() function of std::tr2::sys namespace but it is not available latest vesion of c++, Please suggest me any alternative. Thanks

Comment: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/c17-feature-removals-and-deprecations/  Look for `std::tr2::sys` about half way down.